# Detect resize event in tmux

Tags: tmux

I have a tmux set-up where my top pane is always 2 rows big. Unfortunately every time the terminal gets resized, the proportions are completely reset and the top pane takes up much more space.

I created a binding in my `.tmux.conf` file that allows me to resize the pane by pressing F12: `bind -n F12 resize-pane -t 0 -y 2`

However, It'd like this to be done automatically on every resize event. Is there a way to do this somehow efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following on version 2.7 or so and it seemed to work. You can add a hook to run a tmux command on several events, and in particular it seems that `window-layout-changed` gets triggered when panes are resized.  I tried the obvious

```
set-hook -g window-layout-changed 'resize-pane -t 0 -y 2'
```

but that created an infinite loop. Some events have an *after* version, but apparently there is no `after-window-layout-changed` event. (Earlier versions of tmux have a `layout-changed` event, but I couldn't get it to work).

So finally, I created a small shell script, `myscript`, in my `PATH` to check the current size of the pane and only resize it if necessary:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ht=$(tmux display-message -p -t 0 '#{pane_height}')
if [ 2 != "$ht" ]
then tmux display-panes\; resize-pane -t 0 -y 2
fi
```

I added the `display-panes` just to see if the script was running. This seemed to work well with:

```
set-hook -g window-layout-changed 'run-shell myscript'
```

and even in the case where there was only pane 0 left (which was therefore un-resizable).

Comment: You're a gentleman, and a scholar!